# memcached log mysql

Tags: mysql, logging, memcached

I run a php code to memcache datas.
Installed PHP5-memcache, memcached, mysql on a debian system.
Up to date.

But, I noticed that even if my php code finds the key/value, there is still a sql query made.

Here are the steps :
1) Set key/value using the Memcache class
2) Going on another page
3) Getting back on the page, so that it should get the key/value. Nothing else changed, the cache is set to 1000 seconds.

I put echos so that I know what is going on : it answers me that it found the set/value pair.

But my mysql log tells me that the query is still performed.

Is it a normal situation, I mean, that the query log is showing the same query over and over following my website navigation ?

This question is very theory oriented.

Many thanks,

See U

Comment: Are you checking cache value before making a new query? So, `if($mem->get('value') === null) runNewQuery()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah !! Got it !

I was using php5-memcached, which is a bit wicked on Debian as it seems.

php5-memcache, instead, works flawlessly.

So, I think everything is okay.

Thanks Qeremy